# Why it is giving error "segmentation fault"?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, char-pointer

I want to input two strings at different memory locations but after taking the first input it shows an error "segmentation fault(core dumped"). I am not getting what's wrong with this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *str;
    int i;
    scanf("%s",str+0);
    scanf("%s",str+1);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I only take one input it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *str;
    int i;
    scanf("%s",str+0);

    return 0;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Why do you have `#include<iostream>` and `using namespace std;`? They are used in C++, not C.

Comment: "*But when i take only one input it works fine.*" Both the code exhibits Undefined Behavior. And UB means anything can happen. It might work, might not, or do something else. Avoid UB at all costs. Don't rely on that behavior.

Comment: Can you also show your input.

Comment: @ArunA.S , Why? It is certain that both the code is wrong as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @CoolGuy , that is correct, but I was just wondering what the OP was intending to do with those two `scanf()`'s in his first code with `%s`

Comment: `str+0` is the same as `str`. Why are you using `+0`?

Comment: I was just editing the previous code.

Comment: naresh@ubuntu:~$ g++ c_concept.cpp 
naresh@ubuntu:~$ ./a.out
naresh
naresh@ubuntu:~$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you do not allocate any memory to `str` before using it in your `scanf()`.

You need to allocate some memory with `malloc()`

Both your codes exhibit [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you try to access unsafe memory.